# Roomle Rubens MOC SDK Integration - hiding the "Add to basket" Button

Tags: roomle

It's not possible to hide the "add to basket" button while also showing the "requestplan" button.

How can the "add to basket" button be disabled?

I tried this configuration:

buttons:
add_to_basket: false
requestplan: true

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct and it seem the implementation for hiding the add to basket button is missing.

Please open a bug issue using this URL and our dev team will fix it with an upcoming release: https://roomle.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/4/group/5/create/24